# Crystal Reports 2020-Display subreport in sequence, i.e. when subreport 1 is finished, subreport 2 starts on a new page

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

Crystal Reports 2020-Display subreport in order, i.e. when subreport 1 is finished, subreport 2 starts on a new page.
I have tried it with By page, but it does not work properly.

I have tried it with By page, but it does not work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear but, in general, to force something to start on a new page, place it in a different section. You can then turn on the 'New Page Before' property for that section.

For example, if your 1st subreport is in the Report Footer section, use 'Insert Section Below' to split RF to RFa and RFb. Keep the 1st subreport in RFa and move the 2nd subreport to RFb. Turn on the 'New Page Before' for RFb (or turn on the 'New Page After' property for RFa).